# Apache default site configuration

Tags: apache, server, apache2

I see strange behavior in my `apache2` sites.

I've 3 sites:

1. `https://example.com`: Homepage - Just some HTML, CSS, JS files.
2. `https://node1.example.com`: A nodeJS app
3. `https://ruby1.example.com`: A rails app

All the above three are pointing to `1.2.3.4`. I've disabled `000-default-site` in apache and enabled all the above three. When I browse the above domains, they all work fine.

The problem is when I browse `1.2.3.4`, I sometimes see my NodeJS site or Ruby Site or sometimes my homepage. When people type `1.2.3.4`, this should always show me my Homepage and not the others. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by creating a catch-all virtual host.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but can you explain, in detial, what this does exactly?

Comment: Workaround I found is to enable `000-default` which apache provides. Using `ServerName 1.2.3.4` and Document root to same path as my home page.